# How to run localhost on different port if current port is broadcast on ngrok?

Tags: next.js, localhost, ngrok

I am using Next.js and trying to continue developing while the service is on the internet. Is there any way to change the port to do that? When I switch the port the port which was used for the ngrok also changes.